# try to make a report by using awk

Tags: awk

I have a report same as below content:

```
gold     1      1986    USA                 Americal Eagle
gold     1      1908    Austria-Hungary     Franz Josef 100 Korona
silver  10      1981    USA             Ingot
gold     1      1984    Switzerland         ingot
gold     1      1979    RSA                 Krugerrand
gold     0.5    1981    RSA                 Krugerrand
gold     0.1    1986    PRC                 Panda
silver   1      1986    USA                 Liberty dollar
gold     0.25   1986    USA                 Liberty 5-collar piece
silver   0.5    1986    USA                 Liberty 50-cent piece
silver   1      1987    USA                 Constitution dollar
gold     0.25   1987    USA                 Constitution 5-dollar piece
gold     1      1988    Canada              Maple Leaf
```

I want to extract a report like below:

```
Gold pieces:                    9
Weight of gold pieces:           6.10
Value of gold pieces:       9729.50
```

this the code I've made:

```
BEGIN{}
$1 ~/^gold$/
{
  goldWeight += $2
  ++goldCounter
}
END{
  printf "Gold Pieces:\t\t%d\n" , goldCounter
  printf "Weight of gold pieces:\t\t%1.2f\n" , goldWeight
  printf "Value of gold pieces:\t\t%1.2f\n" , goldWeight*1771.00
}
```

the code does not work. where is my problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the first bracket after the pattern

```
$1 ~/^gold$/ {
  goldWeight += $2
  ++goldCounter
}
```

Then the bit in braces applies to the pattern. Otherwise it applies to every line.